# Is there anything wrong with java-package?

Tags: java, jdk, oracle, jre

There is a question about [How can I install Sun/Oracle's proprietary Java JDK 6/7/8 or JRE?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-sun-oracles-proprietary-java-jdk-6-7-8-or-jre) There are 23 answers at the moment, most of them are either explaining how to do it manually (unpack, move file, create links, ...) or how to add a PPA and install a package, and none of them mentions using `java-package` to create your own deb package.

Creating your own deb package is very easy:

You install `java-package`

```
sudo apt-get install java-package
```

You download the Oracle tar.gz archive.
You create your deb package

```
fakeroot make-jpkg jdk-7u79-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

An you install it

```
sudo dpkg -i oracle-java7-jdk_7u79_amd64.deb
```

Am I missing something? Is there any reason not to use `java-package`? Something wrong with it?

Comment: Maybe no one noticed it before, and you should post this as an answer to that question!

Comment: If it helps, there's a reasonably upvoted Stack Overflow post mentioning this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28863828/2072269

Comment: I couldn't as it's a protected question and the 100 association bonus doesn't count toward the 10 rep needed to reply.

Comment: Didn't see that. It was on 5 upvotes versus 297 for the top answer, that's quite sad. Well, I guess that question was asking for JDK, not specifically the Oracle one, but still.